# Remove beginning and ending of file names in shell

Tags: shell, rename

I want to rename my phone screenshot with the name:
`Screenshot_2020-08-06-16-13-43-731_com.tclhz.gallery.jpg` to `2020-08-06.jpg`

Regarding the fixed parts of the file name, I want to generalize it so I can remove N first characters and N last characters.

How to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: `mv Screenshot_2020-08-06-16-13-43-731_com.tclhz.gallery.jpg 2020-08-06.jpg` – But this is so basic. Or do you want to *automate* it for filenames matching some pattern? Then it's more interesting. Formal note: in Unix `.jpg` belongs to the filename, so your example does not remove the ending, it removes a fragment near the end; the title is thus somewhat misleading.

Comment: How do you guarantee there is only one screenshot per day? The timestamp is there to avoid duplicates (at least, down to the millisecond level).

Comment: Another program would take care of that. This would be one of the steps in the pipeline (the next would move the screenshot to a diferent folder where it would be appended with 1, 2, 3 if another screenshot of the same name exists). ;)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following information: What are the fixed parts of the original filename. Is it always `Screenshot_YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss_com.tclhz.gallery.jpg`, or is it more variable, as in `Screenshot_YYYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss_any-string.jpg` (or yet something else)? The actual answer will depend on that. Also, please indicate what you already tried, so that contributors don't point you in a direction that you already know doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shell string manipulation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) functions for that.
Assuming your filename is stored in a variable `name`, the following two lines will remove everything up to and including the first underscore, and then everything starting with the `-hh-mm-ss` part. The filename extension is then re-added by hand.

```bsh
newname="${name#*_}"
newname="${newname%-??-??-??-*}.jpg"
```

Then, you can issue the command

```bsh
mv "$name" "$newname"
```

to rename the files.

Example:

```
$ name="Screenshot_2020-08-06-16-13-43-731_com.tclhz.gallery.jpg"
$ newname="${name#*_}"; newname="${newname%-??-??-??-*}.jpg"; echo "$newname"
2020-08-06-16.jpg
```

In order to process the entire content of the current directory:

```bsh
for name in *.jpg
do
    newname="${name#*_}"
    newname="${newname%-??-??-??-*}.jpg"
    mv "$name" "$newname"
done
```